# laravel - get value from url

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-oauth

I know that this might be a off question or can be duplicate but after searching a lot I decided to post this question. I am using Socialite with laravel and I am still a newbie to it. I decided to have twitter login. I did everything but at last I didn't know how to get values such as `oauth_verifier` and `oauth_token` to a variable from the URL

`example.com/callback?oauth_token=xyz&oauth_verifier=123` .

I want to check those values. I have already tried it using `\Input::get('oauth_verifier')` and `isset($_GET('oauth_verifier'))` but didn't get any output each time. Please help.

Comment: Did you try \Request::get() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is function `user()` which gives you all possible values you can get with Socialize. Try this

```
$user = Socialize::with('twitter')->user();
dd($user);
```